# Get BBM Chat Logs

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

A Simple question for every one , is there any possible way to get Blackberry BBM Logs in application , via Programming.

Following task I have done :-

> 1. Download & integrate BBM SDK in Project.
> 2. Follow the [BBM Development Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36637/Overview_1323631_11.jsp).

Here are My Code :-

```
public void getBBM_Logs()
    {
        BBMPlatformContext platformContext =null;
        try 
        {
            platformContext = BBMPlatformManager.register(new MyBBMAppPlugin());


            if(platformContext != null)
            {
                ContactListService contactListService = platformContext.getContactListService();
                BBMPlatformContactList contacts = contactListService.getContactList();
                Enumeration contactsEnum = contacts.getAll();

                while(contactsEnum.hasMoreElements())
                { 
                    BBMPlatformContact contact = (BBMPlatformContact)contactsEnum.nextElement();

                    add(new LabelField(contact.getDisplayName()));
                }

            }

        }
        catch (ControlledAccessException e) 
        {
            // The BBM platform has been disabled
        }


        if (platformContext != null) 
        {
            MyBBMPlatformContextListener platformContextListener;
            platformContextListener = new MyBBMPlatformContextListener();
            platformContext.setListener(platformContextListener);
        }

    }


    private class MyBBMPlatformContextListener extends BBMPlatformContextListener
    {
        public void accessChanged(boolean isAccessAllowed, int accessErrorCode)
        {
            if (!isAccessAllowed)
            {
                // You cannot access the BBM platform
            }
        }

        public void appInvoked(int reason, Object param)
        {
            // Code for handling different contexts for invocation
        }
    }

    private class MyBBMAppPlugin extends BBMPlatformApplication
    {
        public MyBBMAppPlugin()
        {
            super("57888721-1e52-4171-a8a4-0559eab8efdf");
        }
    }
```

Please Let Me know , is there any possible way to get ChatLogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not possible - as I think BB regard access to chat logs from a program as a potential security exposure.